# Error: Objective function must return a scalar-Python Optimization?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When i run Python minimize function on my objective function , i get Objective function must return a scalar error.

```
def fun(param,*args):

    alpha=param[0];
    beta=param[1:len(param)]
    t_to_next =args[1] 
    remaining_coupons = args[2]
    coupon_rate = args[3]
    dirty_price = args[4]
    knots = args[5]

    fit_P = []
    f = []
    fit_price = 0.0
    for i in range(0,len(t_to_next)): #first loop for the number of securities
        fit_price=0
        for j in range(0,remaining_coupons[i]):  #second loop for the number of cashflows * m_t
            x = zero_price(t_to_next[i]+0.5*(j),alpha,beta,knots)
            fit_price = fit_price + (float(coupon_rate[i])*0.01 * float(x))

        fit_P.append(fit_price + zero_price(t_to_next[i]+0.5*(remaining_coupons[i]-1),alpha,beta,knots))
        #fit_P.append(fit_price)
        f.append((dirty_price[i]/100 - fit_P[i])**2)

    f_sum=sum(f)
    return f_sum
```

and my call to above function is:

```
result = optimize.minimize(fun, initial_guess,args=additional,constraints=cons,method='SLSQP',
                           options={'xtol': 1e-8, 'disp': True})
```

Comment: I was able to solve the above problem, just updating my comment so in case someone face this type of issue, the cause of the problem was due to overflow in math.exp instead replacing math.exp by np.exp solved the problem